# is it possible to set a discount code for full price items only

Tags: magento

I'd like to be able to set a discount code which is only applied to full price items - eg not special prices items. Is this possible? Or is there an extension that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer on the Magento forum:

In Promotions > Shopping cart price rules > Actions

Make the condition

If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :

to

If ALL of these conditions are FALSE :

Then

Special Price equals or greater than 0

[image]

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/20641/

The only problem now, is that the cart error message is confusing - the default message is Coupon code “%s” is not valid. (%s replaces the coupon code).

In order to change this, edit the Mage_Checkout.csv language file (app/local/{lang_ISO}) and change the translation to this message to whatever you want.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/290271/